# Generate an array of N elements containing the first n values of z_n

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have been given the following assignment:

> Write a function that can generate an array with N elements. The values are mathematically defined as:
>
> z_n = alpha (1+sqrt{3})^n + beta (1-sqrt{3})^n for all n>=1
>
> The number of elements and the two real numbers alpha and beta are given as input. Output should be a vector with the first n values.

Along with this code, which I have to complete:

```
def make_sequence(N:int, alpha:float, beta:float) -> np.ndarray:
    return
```

This is what I have been able to come up with:

```
def make_sequence(N:int, alpha:float, beta:float) -> np.ndarray:
    z_n = np.empty((N, 1))
    N = 10
    n = 1
    for alpha in range(1, N):
        z_n[n] = alpha*(1+sqrt(3))^n + beta*(1-sqrt(3))^n
        n += 1
    return z_n
```

Can anybody help me get it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem**: the `^` is the **bitwise xor operation**, not **power**. In that case you can use `**`. Furthermore you **assign to `alpha`** in the `for` loop.

So you can solve it like:

```
def make_sequence(N:int, alpha:float, beta:float) -> np.ndarray:
    result = np.empty((N, 1))
    for n in range(1, N+1):
        result[n-1] = alpha*(1+sqrt(3))**n + beta*(1-sqrt(3))**n
    return result
```

Nevertheless, you can make it more declarative by first generate an `arange`, and then **use broadcasting**:

```
def make_sequence(N:int, alpha:float, beta:float) -> np.ndarray:
    result = np.arange(1,N+1)
    return alpha*(1+sqrt(3))**result + beta*(1-sqrt(3))**result
```

For 10 elements with `alpha=0.5` and `beta=0.25`, we get:

```
>>> make_sequence(10,0.5,0.25)
array([  1.18301270e+00,   3.86602540e+00,   1.00980762e+01,
         2.79282032e+01,   7.60525589e+01,   2.07961524e+02,
         5.68028166e+02,   1.55197938e+03,   4.24001509e+03,
         1.15839890e+04])
```

Comment: Running  

The code above followed by  `make_sequence(10,0.5,0.25)`,

I get:

"IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10  

Process finished with exit code 1"

Comment: @user405381: yes, the index of course should be `n-1` and not `n`. Fixed